# How can i make mediawiki installation and wordpress installation in the same domain share the same user login and session information?

Tags: wordpress, mediawiki

I have a wordpress site installed at the root of a domain. I have installed mediawiki in the directory "wiki" at the domain root. Now i want the mediawiki to share the user session info, even the user credentials with wordpress. I want to make mediawiki recognize a user as logged in if he is logged in to tho the wordpress. I have tried with the following online links. But none of them works for the latest of mediawiki versions.

1. https://dev.commons.gc.cuny.edu/2009/05/21/new-mediawiki-extension-wpmusinglesignon/
2. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WPMW

If anyone could help to achieve this ?

Comment: Start researching for this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=CUSTOM_USER_TABLE

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share session information between MediaWiki and another application (and it's generally an anti-pattern; sessions are meant to hold application-specific information). You can use Wordpress login information in your wiki by using an extension that implements either a [PrimaryAuthenticationProvider](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#PrimaryAuthenticationProvider) (for checking against Wordpress credentials when using the MediaWiki login form) or a [SessionProvider](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager#SessionProvider) (for checking against the WordPress session cookie, or otherwise authenticating every request). It's not an easy task if you need to write that extension yourself. WPMW looks like the right thing in theory, but it has not been updated for a while.

Comment: Thaks for your comment. I am trying this hard myself. But no luck. I am looking for a developer who can help to achieve this. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Professional_development_and_consulting) or [this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Jobs).